# Amazon S3 download time without network delays

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to get the download time of a file in S3 without the transfer rate. Just the disk reading speed.

Comment: Give us more context. You want to do it prior to downloading the file or as it is being downloaded? Doing it prior to downloading means you have to estimate the connection speed. Doing it while downloading means you have to calculate the ongoind speed.

Comment: Small file or big file? Have you tried timing a download already? If you can provide more information, we can provide more assistance.

Comment: @Finch_Powers I want to compare the download time of amazon S3 and the file system of MongoDB which is GridFS. But since GridFS is done locally and S3 has delays due to the network/internet I do not know how to compare them. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  I want to compare the download time of amazon S3 and the file system of MongoDB which is GridFS. But since GridFS is done locally and S3 has delays due to the network/internet I do not know how to compare them. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The transfer rate can be generalized to the slowest speed between disk reads and internet transfer rate. You say you want to remove the transfer rate from the equation. So my understanding is that you want to calculate the disk reading speed of S3? Why? I probably don't get your case right.

Comment: @Finch_Powers yes i want to remove the transfer rate and calculate the disk reading speed of S3. Just for comparison.

Comment: Then you should edit/rephrase your question to that. I don't see the point though since as a user it doesn't matter: you are going to get the speed of what is slowest between the disk or the connection.